# How to change of generated file in TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio

sometime ago I started using TeXstudio (on Windows 10). Learning of latex and its commands is not easy, but also not difficult. But still there is one thing I would like to do: generate pdf files of the same name as *project*, instead of `main.pdf` as it is in default setting.

May it be I am only blind and don't see place where it can be set in TeXstudio. But may it be that it is needed to use another command inside tex files (mostly main.tex).

Please, tell me how to do it (how to change name of generated pdf file in TeXstudio).

Comment: why not save the main.tex file to a name of your liking and then set this file as the root document? The pdf will then have that name.

Comment: the pdf file is written by tex not your editor (texstudio) by default it has the same name as your document file, with `.tex` changed to `.pdf`

Comment: It is clear that pdf is not generated by TeXstudio, itself, but I supposed that there is option in settings that may affect it.

Comment: @bkleine, you was the first, thanks - it runs. Write it as regular answer and you have plus points. I think it may be very useful also for other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save the main file to a name of your liking; then to set this file as the root document. The pdf generated will then have the name of the root file.